# Sending search form submit to a particular controller method

Tags: search, ruby-on-rails-4, view

Windows 8
Rails 4.1
Ruby 2.0

I have the following search form in my menu:

```
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" method="get" name="search-form" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

When I submit, I would like to call a particular method in the agents controller. I tried:

```
<input type="text" method="get" name="search-form" action="agents_search_view" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
```

but it did not work. I also tried:

```
<button type="submit" action="agents_search_view" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

but it did not work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be adding **`action`** in the **`form tag`**,not in the **`input`** and not in the **`submit button`**.

This should work

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="agents_search_view">
   <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" method="get" name="search-form" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
   </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```